# Reporting Services aggregate function for row group

Tags: reporting-services

I've created a report featuring a 'tablix' that uses a dataset based on sales data. The sales data is grouped by date and UPC; appended to this dataset are product attributes and an inventory quantity, an example of data is:

```
date     upc           qty_sold  style  color  size  on_hand_inventory
1/1/13   123456789111         5  abc    black  m                    50
1/1/13   123456789112         4  abc    black  l                    40
1/2/13   123456789111         2  abc    black  l                    40
1/2/13   123456789114         5  efg    red    m                    70
1/3/13   123456789115         4  efg    red    l                    20
1/1/13   123456789114         2  efg    red    m                    70
```

I have the product attributes (style, color, size) as row groups and the inventory qty as a column.

The row inventory is correct, but the totals always show many multiples of the inventory qtys. This is because, for example, abc-black-m could show up on one day only, but abc-black-l could show up on many days, so the inventory qty for the group abc-black sums all the abc-black-l rows and a single abc-black-m row.

I need the correct formula for totaling the row groups' inventory. It basically just needs to sum the on_hand_inventory column if the UPC hasn't been sum'ed already.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the semantics of the "correct formula", what does "if the UPC hasn't been sum'ed already" mean?

Comment: @Jeroen is right, you need to provide more info. I can't see what the correct formula for `UPC hasn't be sum'ed already` is.

Comment: In the data there are two abc-black-l and one abc-black-m. If I want to get the on_hand_inventory total for the abc-black group in a tablix the regular sum() function gives me 130 (40+40+50), but it should be 90 (50+40). So, when I say I need to "sum if the UPC hasn't been counted already" I mean a formula to sum() the inventory that will only count the on_hand_inventory column once per UPC. There might be a better way to do it however... I just don't know it.

Comment: Couple of questions - can you please confirm what SQL Server version you're using? And is the dataset above an exact representation of the columns in the report dataset and an accurate example of what it might return, i.e. no grouping has been applied, these are the actual rows being returned?

Comment: SQL Server 9.0.4060. The data is grouped by date and UPC already, although it doesn't need to be because I could do that in SSRS too; the only columns missing from that example are product descriptions and columns representing the month/year/week number of the date column.

Comment: I suggest you work on your initial sql and have a grouped column based on your unique criteria. Try using window funcions.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a separate dataset for the inventory and using the LookupSet function to get the inventory total.